# How do i get my android widget in the right size on start?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, size, homescreen

I have the following problem:

I have a android widget with a listview and my widget_info.xml looks like this:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:minHeight="65dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:minResizeWidth="250dp"
android:minResizeHeight="65dp">
</appwidget-provider>
```

When i set the widget on the homescreen it sometimes dont have the minimum height.

You have to know, my listview is empty at start an get filled after the start. But when its filled it have to show the widget with minimum height, but it does not.

I mean sometime it does and sometimes not. Is it a bug or a feature? How can i handle this?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Since i have set the android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="match_parent" it works fine! :)